# Allowed named subpattern characters

Tags: php, regex, escaping, preg-match, character

What characters are allowed in named subpattern and is it possible to escape inside named subpattern?

```
(?<name>\w+)
```

I want to use this example http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php#example-3946 and want to have "hello-name" instead of "name" for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PCRE only allows alphanumeric characters and underscores for subpattern names:
http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/Documentation/pcre/pcrepattern.html#SEC14

Comment: What is the regex of a valid name?

Comment: Safest to assume `[a-z]\w*` as always.